Does quantization challenge infinity?
Please bear with me as I try to explain the question I asked myself today: Does quantization challenge the idea of the infinitely small?
We seem to easily consider "the infinitely large" and "the infinitely small" as more or less symmetrical. However large your number is, there is a small equivalent which is just as small as the later is big. It seems symmetric.
In mathematics, pure and abstract, of course the infinitely small and large exist. They are manipulated, used, and reused and are fairly comprehensible mathematical tools with real implications. Say you integrate over all space: you are using both concepts (the concept of an infinite "total volume" and the concept of differentials and the infinitely small).
However, in physics I have been stumped by something. One might say that the infinitely small, in physics, is limited because we simply will find a 'stopping point' at which we cannot divide matter anymore. First it was larger materials, then cells, molecules, atoms, quarks... and it goes on. However, there must be a limit? Does this challenge the concept of the infinitely small? If so, or if not, is there literature I could read up on to better understand and gain some insight?
Another way in which physics gives me trouble with the infinite is how quantizations arises when we look at small phenomenon. A particle exhibiting quantum levels, for instance. The quantization of energy states of a particle in a box. Does the very idea of quantization bring a challenge to further divide? How can we be left with integer results? How are integer results a fact of the world?
I guess you could say no, quantization does not defy the infinitely small, because of the following example: take a guitar string. It has quantized modes. This does not mean that the guitar string cannot be reduced down into smaller parts. The fact that its modes are quantized says nothing about the reducibility, or any sort of infinity.
However, the question that I am bringing up would only consider the quantized modes themselves. We cannot reduce the modes further, brake them down. They are mathematical objects, say a certain frequency. They are absolute. Again, How can integer results be a fact of the world?
The question is hard to elaborate because it came to me today as more of an intuition. However, I feel that this may be something interesting to explore. I would really love to hear any thoughts, and especially any literature which could be interesting about this topic.

In physics, if you assemble too much matter it will collapse into a black hole, speeds are limited by the speed of light, and there are all other sorts of size limitations for specific phenomena. But how does existence of such limitations for modes, or some other physical entities, challenge the idea of infinitely large or small?

I don't suppose you happen to be 2/3 through an undergrad physics curriculum or all the way through an undergrad chemistry or nuclear engineering program?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

From time to time someone rediscovers equations that are not so quantisized. Such as the electron "jump" being continu motion in space and time and not a sudden discontinu jump in space and time. Speed is also not quantized I think. Nice question +1

Even if the world/universe/... turns out to be finite with a hard upper bound, there is still an important role for all sorts of infinities in mathematics.
To understand why, we should ask ourselves why we use infinity in mathematics?    The point is that our various infinite objects have nice closure properties.  These lead to an elegant system from which we can draw neat conclusions.  We could perhaps get fairly far with finite approximations, but those tend to be messy.  We as finite beings have only got so much time, computing power, etc.
As an example: one can develop calculus over the rational numbers, but it is much less elegant/more messy than calculus over the real numbers.
This does not imply that these infinities "really exist" (whatever that means), but it does suggest an important role for infinitary mathematics: making the development of physics quicker/faster/easier.
Moreover: quantum limitations, Planck scale, etc. apply to real numbers just as much as they do to infinitesimals.  So really the OP is wondering about the applicability of real numbers in physics, and not just infinitesimals.  This was implicit in my first answer.

In quantum theory, the evolution of a physical system is described by Hermitian operators called observables. The possible results of measurements of those observables are their eigenvalues. Quantum theory predicts the expectation values of those observables, which is the sum of the possible values weighted by their probabilities which are real numbers. A system moves from one state to the other by continuous change of probabilities not by continuous change of directly measurable values:
https://www.daviddeutsch.org.uk/wp-content/ItFromQubit.pdf
For systems with a finite amount of energy in a finite region, i.e. - all measurable physical systems, the relevant observables generally have a finite number of possible values as explained by Bekenstein in "Universal upper bound on the entropy-to-energy ratio for bounded systems":
https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.23.287
To use the string analogy, there is a limit to how fast a plucked string can vibrate before it breaks or collapses into a black hole and so there is a limit to how many states it can have.

Whether we talk about a guitar string or a particle in a box, the quantization arises, because the system is finite - take a larger/shorter string or a larger/smaller box, and the energy levels/modes become closer/further to each other (the effect is actually used when we shorten guitar string to get higher sounds.) If a string is infinitely long, its spectrum is continuous - a mode of any frequency can travel in it. Likewise, if the box is infinitely large (no box), then particle levels are continuous - there is no quantization.
I recall an introduction to a physics textbook, where the author says that he hopes the reader to have a feeling of slight disappointment after finishing the book - because the concepts that seem mysterious to a person unfamiliar with the subject, are often pretty simple and obvious, once one understands what is actually meant. I think this is very much true for much what is said about relativity, quantization, machine learning, evolution and other things - if just a fraction of time that people spend on debating about these things were invested in actually learning what they mean, the debates would be unnecessary.
Hopefully, this answer leaves you disappointed.


Your post touches a wide range of questions:

Does quantization challenge the idea of the infinitely small?
Does the very idea of quantization bring a challenge to further    divide?
How can we be left with integer results?
How are integer results a fact of the world?

It seems that you just present your thoughts. Possibly you did not
look up some references from the physics literature before.

A good start is to inform yourself about the concept of those
minimal quantities from physics which set the Planck scale as a
limit to our present theories:

Planck length, Planck time, Planck energy

All three quantities combine the universal constants which govern
most of present physics. For an introduction see Planck_units.



The Planck energy is the energy released by blowing up half a tonne of TNT. Planck units do not describe limits to our theories. They are just the values you get when you algebraically combine universal constants until you get units with the appropriate dimension.

Some of the Planck units do approximately coincide with some limits to theory or measurement for certain kinds of systems, by matching the minimal or maximal order of magnitude for which measurement is possible or certain simplifying assumptions adequately describe the domain without the introduction of corrective terms.
